# backup file descriptor of stdout, to restore printing on to terminal later using only dup2, without using dup system call in C

Tags: c, file-descriptor, dup2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main()
{
    int stdout_fd   = dup2(1, 1);
    printf("stdout_fd:%d\n", stdout_fd);
    
    int fd_file     = open("file.txt", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
    fd_file         = dup2(fd_file, 1);
    printf("file descriptor of file.txt : %d\n", fd_file);
    
    fd_file         = dup2(fd_file, stdout_fd);
    printf("file descriptor of file.txt : %d\n", fd_file);
    return 0;
}
O/P:
stdout
______
stdout_fd:1                                                                                                                                                 

file.txt
________
file descriptor of file.txt : 1
file descriptor of file.txt : 1
```

Here I am trying to print first time to required "file.txt" instead of stdout
then for 2nd printf, I am trying to print on stdout i.e, restore file descriptor 0 from from file.txt to stdout again.

> I want to implement it using only dup2, without using dup.
> I dont want to use something like below

```
int stdout_fd = dup(fd_file);
dup2(fd_file, 1);
printf("I am printing on file.txt");
dup2(fd_file, stdout_fd);
printf("I am printing on file.txt");
```

Comment: I will do it, but could you tell how to do it using dup2 alone, without dup system call @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Please read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [dup(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) and study for inspiration the C source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or of [sash](http://members.canb.auug.org.au/~dbell/) or of [zsh](https://zsh.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i read man page for dup, dup2. it doesn't help for my requirement @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: "without using dup" Why? This doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: its my assignment, so they asked me to do only using dup2 which I am unable to get it. using dup with dup2 as mentioned above, i am able to shuffle between stdout and file.txt for printing.
But dup2 alone, i am not getting @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: Notice that `dup` and `dup2` are *closely related*; you just have to *carefully read* their documentation and understand deeply what are [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)s. See also [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

Comment: Take a few days to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and to study, for inspiration, the [C source code of `sash`](http://members.canb.auug.org.au/~dbell/). Use also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) -on  `/bin/sash`  and `/bin/bash` ...- and compile your C code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Read also of course [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [close(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Try `ls -l /proc/$$/fd/` and `cat /proc/self/maps`. Read a good [operating system texbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: You need to call [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and to study the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) - since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)